# Take a picture every 20 seconds forever

Tags: android, bitmap, camera, out-of-memory

I have an old Android device (Android 4.1.2, API 16) which I want to use as a "CCTV-like" device. I need to take a picture every 20 seconds and to do this I have implemented the following code on an Activity.
The onCreate() method is as the following:

```
//To keep the display on (the phone is always attached to the power supply)  
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

FrameLayout preview = findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);

initializeCamera();

Timer timerPhoto = new Timer();
timerPhoto.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPictureCallback);
               mCamera.startPreview();
            }
        }, 5000, 20000); //start after 5 seconds, take pic every 20 secs
```

The following method for the camera initialisation:

```
private void initializeCamera() {
        if (mCamera == null) {
            mCamera = getCameraInstance();
            Timber.d("Camera initialized");
        }
        mCameraPreview = new IaCameraHelper(this, mCamera);
        preview.addView(mCameraPreview);
    }
```

And this is the callback which handles the picture:

```
 private static Bitmap originalPhotoBitmap = null;

 Camera.PictureCallback mPictureCallback = (data, camera) -> {
        originalPhotoBitmap = addDateTimeToImage(rotateBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length), 180));

        //Sending the bitmap string to the server
        controller.sendImage(bitmapToString(originalPhotoBitmap));

        originalPhotoBitmap.recycle();
        BitmapManager.rotatedBitmap.recycle();
        BitmapManager.modBitmap.recycle();

        originalPhotoBitmap = null;
        BitmapManager.rotatedBitmap = null;
        BitmapManager.modBitmap = null;

 };
```

In the BitmapManager, I have the following methods which have been used to manipulate the bitmap:

```
public static Bitmap rotatedBitmap = null;
public static Bitmap modBitmap = null;

public static Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap source, float angle) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    return rotatedBitmap;
}

public static Bitmap addDateTimeToImage(Bitmap originalPhoto) {

    modBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalPhoto.getWidth(), originalPhoto.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    String dateTime = sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    Canvas cs = new Canvas(modBitmap);
    Paint tPaint = new Paint();
    tPaint.setTextSize(30);
    tPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    tPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    cs.drawBitmap(originalPhoto, 0f, 0f, null);
    float height = tPaint.measureText("yY");
    cs.drawText(dateTime, 20f, height + 15f, tPaint);
    return modBitmap;
}

public static String bitmapToString(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    return Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

As you can see, I send the bitmap string to a controller which sends the image to a local server in the network. 
Generally, the application works like a charm, but sometimes (generally after 6-7 hours) I face the following errors (out-of-memory) that I don't know how to solve.

```
02-21 13:12:03.292 29621-29632/com.rbapp E/dalvikvm-heap: Out of memory on a 127547-byte allocation.
02-21 13:12:03.302 29621-29632/com.rbapp E/Camera-JNI: Couldn't allocate byte array for JPEG data
```

As you can see, I try to recycle all the generated bitmaps and I set them to null as soon as I send them to the controller, but the error persists.
When the errors occur, the application continues to run (also the camera preview), but the images are not sent (there are try-catches which allows the execution of the app) but as I press the "back" button on the phone, the application doesn't respond at all.

Comment: I forgot to mention that in the manifest, under the application tag, I have already added the following statement: **android:largeHeap="true"**

Comment: Have you tried debugging with Android Studio's profiler? You can track allocations and see which can't be freed.

Comment: What is `controller`? If `sendImage` runs asynchronously, it's easy to image many huge `Strings` queueing up on the client due to an (as yet undiagnosed) network problem.

Comment: controller is a method used to send a command on the eventbus (from greenrobot), that command has inside the data, which will be captured by a remote controller which sends that data remotely. I don't think that it is the issue here, I've already done a lot of other application with the same rationale which work without any problem.
I am going to try to figure out what consumes the memory with the profiler, but I receive "no debuggable processes" in Android, this maybe is because of the old API device.

Comment: I have substituted the controller with a well-known method for updating the picture (private static class SendImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {}) (similarly to this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30645668/android-take-more-picture-from-camera-couldnt-allocate-byte-array-for-jpeg-dat ) but the problem persists.